# HTML JS Как задать изначальные значения в indexeddb

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Имеется база данных indexeddb внутри браузера. Как задать ей изначальные значения? Например пользователь заходит в первый раз, значения по умолчанию создаются в базе. Потом пользователь работает с сайтом, база данных меняется и при последующем открывании сайта, чтобы уже сайт сам не задавал значения по умолчанию. Идея удалять все, потом добавлять не катит, нужно только при первом запуске.

Comment: Так а если при первом входе создать все, что надо, а при последующих входах проверять, если база не пустая - использовать то, что уже есть?

Comment: Алгоритм решения есть в вопросе, и есть оператор `if`, который позволяет решить эту задачу. Так в чем конкретно возникли трудности?